# How to resolve 'Maximum execution time 30 seconds exceeded error', even after setting up max_execution_time=3600

Tags: php

**Fatal error:Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\inetpub\wwwroot*.php on line ##.**

My *php.ini* already set to:

```
max_execution_time=3600
```

Error line executes a program which takes 2 minutes to execute: It looks like:

```
exec("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/program.cmd");
```

**Note: It runs fine on sever, creates all output files nicely. But throws error to browser page.**
(I restarted the server after changing *php.ini* file)

Comment: rather then increasing the max_execution_time I'd take a look what causes the long execution.

Comment: @cptnk I know the execution takes 60 seconds or more. I can't reduce that.

Comment: maybe the timer also needs to be increased in the server's config file

Comment: @cptnk you are right, if the script is taking so much time, then there's something wrong

Comment: Which php.ini file have you made changes? Can you give full path here?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.ini THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this....

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // zero means takes its own time.
```

This will execute the php program till it is fully executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the execution time dynamically on the same page like this-

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value max_execution_time 0
```